# Android slide menu Center Text in tool bar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have some code and I need to modify it to center a textfield on the toolbar. This is the screen shot: [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDl9c.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDl9c.png

Below is the MainActivity.java

```
package life.poa.webcastman.poa1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import android.view.Display;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    public String tmpemail ;
    public String tmpusername ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.layout.activity_main);

        View bgimage = (View) findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
        bgimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wheat);
        bgimage.setAlpha(1.0f);

        commonfunc.myprint("#####_____mainActivity_onCreateView ");
        //if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        //{
        //    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        //}

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
        commonfunc.myprint("____mainactivity-onCreate 1 : " + width + " " + height);
        DisplayMetrics metrics;
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        height = metrics.heightPixels;
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        commonfunc.myprint("____mainactivity-onCreate 1 : " + width + " " + height);
        float density = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        if (density >= 4.0) {
            commonfunc.myprint("xxxhdpi");
        }
        if (density >= 3.0) {
            commonfunc.myprint("xxhdpi");
        }
        if (density >= 2.0) {
            commonfunc.myprint("xhdpi");
        }
        if (density >= 1.5) {
            commonfunc.myprint("hdpi");
        }
        if (density >= 1.0) {
            commonfunc.myprint("mdpi");
        } else {
            commonfunc.myprint("ldpi");
        }

        // Email
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        tmpemail = preferences.getString(commonfunc.company + "email", "");
        commonfunc.myprint("mainactivity preferences email:" + commonfunc.company + "email: " + tmpemail);
        // Username
        tmpusername = preferences.getString(commonfunc.company + "username", "");
        commonfunc.myprint("mainactivity preferences email:" + commonfunc.company + "email: " + tmpusername);

        //Refresh Token
        String refreshtoken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        String preftoken = preferences.getString(commonfunc.company + "token", "");
        commonfunc.myprint("mainactivity preferences preftoken refreshtoken:" + preftoken + " <-> " + refreshtoken);
        if (refreshtoken != preftoken) {
            editor.putString(commonfunc.company + "token", refreshtoken);
            editor.apply();
            editor.commit();
            String tmptoken = preferences.getString(commonfunc.company + "token", "");
            commonfunc.myprint("mainactivity preferences token recheck:" + commonfunc.company + "token: " + tmptoken);
        }

        //main_started
        String pref_main_started = preferences.getString(commonfunc.company + "main_started", null);
        commonfunc.myprint("mainactivity_onCreateOptionsMenu_preferences main_started 1:" + commonfunc.company + "main_started " + pref_main_started);
        //Gordon Turn Off main_started to null
        if (pref_main_started != null) {
            editor.putString(commonfunc.company + "main_started", null);
            editor.apply();
            editor.commit();
            pref_main_started = preferences.getString(commonfunc.company + "main_started", null);
            commonfunc.myprint("mainactivity_onCreateOptionsMenu_preferences  pref_main_started " + commonfunc.company + "main_started " + pref_main_started);
            editor.putString(commonfunc.company + "main_started", null);
        }
        pref_main_started = preferences.getString(commonfunc.company + "main_started", null);
        commonfunc.myprint("mainactivity_onCreateOptionsMenu_preferences main_started 3:" + commonfunc.company + "main_started " + pref_main_started);

        displaynav();
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    private void displaynav()
    {
        commonfunc.myprint("mainActivity_displaynav ");

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Login
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Create Account
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Calendar
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Live Webcast
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // Live Webcast Archive
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        // My Groups
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
        // MY Group Notifications
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));

        if (tmpemail == null)
        {
            commonfunc.myprint("mainactivity_tmpemail_null:" + tmpemail);
        }
        if (tmpemail.isEmpty())
        {
            commonfunc.myprint("mainactivity_tmpemail_isempty:" + tmpemail);
        }
        if (tmpemail == null || tmpemail.isEmpty())
        {
        }

        if (tmpemail.equals("webcastpoa@gmail.com"))
        {
            commonfunc.myprint("mainactivity_tmpemail:" + tmpemail);
            // MY Play2
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));

            // MY Table2
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
        }


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        //getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar)));

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                commonfunc.myprint("mainActivity_onDrawerClosed ");
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                commonfunc.myprint("mainActivity_onDrawerOpened ");
                //Hide Keyboard GB
                //View view = this.getCurrentFocus();

                if (drawerView != null)
                {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawerView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                }
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        //mDrawerLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);

    }

    /*
    * Slide menu item click listener
    */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            commonfunc.myprint("mainActivity_SlideMenuClickListener ");
            // display view for selected nav drawer item

            displayView(position);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        commonfunc.myprint("mainActivity_onCreateOptionsMenu ");

        getMenuInflater().inflate(life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.menu.main, menu);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        tmpusername = preferences.getString(commonfunc.company + "username", "");
        commonfunc.myprint("mainactivity preferences email:" + commonfunc.company + "email: " + tmpusername);
        setTitle("Welcome " + tmpusername);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        commonfunc.myprint("mainActivity_onOptionsItemSelected ");
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /*
    * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
    */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        commonfunc.myprint("mainActivity_onPrepareOptionsMenu ");


        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        //Turn setting off
        //menu.findItem(life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        menu.findItem(life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.id.action_settings).setVisible(false);

        //01-01-2017 commented
        //SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        //tmpusername = preferences.getString(commonfunc.company + "username", "");
        //commonfunc.myprint("mainactivity preferences email:" + commonfunc.company + "email: " + tmpusername);
        //setTitle("Welcome " + tmpusername);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /*
    * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
    */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        commonfunc.myprint("#####_____mainActivity_displayView ");
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;

        // We allow the Sensor to be used in all instances by default
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new login_login();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new login_create();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new calendar();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new live_webcast();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new live_webcast_archive();
                break;
            case 6:
                /*
                if (tmpemail == null || tmpemail.isEmpty())
                {
                    commonfunc.myprint("my_group_tmpemail null or isempty:" + tmpemail);
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("You Must Create An Account To Join Groups.");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                    return;
                }
                */
                fragment = new my_group();
                break;
            case 7:
                fragment = new my_group_notification();
                break;
            case 8:
                fragment = new my_play2();
                break;
            case 9:
                fragment = new my_table2();
                break;

            default:
                // In just this one instance, we turn the sensor off
                // Until a different menu item is selected, which re-enables it
                //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            //setTitle(navMenuTitles[position] + "Welcome");
            //setTitle("Welcome " + tmpusername);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        else
        {
            // error in creating fragment
            commonfunc.myprint("MainActivity Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        commonfunc.myprint("mainActivity_setTitle ");
        mTitle = title;
        //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /*
    * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
    * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
    */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        commonfunc.myprint("mainActivity_onPostCreate ");
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        commonfunc.myprint("mainActivity_onConfigurationChanged ");
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
        />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to add a margin left on the title to have it centered thanks

Answer (score 0):

don't do much things you can set your space from navigation by..

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setContentInsetStartWithNavigation(50);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(title);
```

Comment: then your question title should be .... Android slide menu Center Text in Action Bar